# Как в Symfony 4.0.6 настроить подключение к базе данных

Tags: php, symfony

в каком файле и что писать для подключения к `mysql`
,вот что показывает при в воде в консоль

**php bin/console --version**

```
4.0.6 (kernel: src, env: dev, debug: true)
```

Comment: Давно с ним не работал, но вроде файл app/config/parameters.yml

Comment: в версии 2 это так но в 4 уже по другому

Comment: Судя по demo-app https://github.com/symfony/demo в **config/packages/doctrine.yaml**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в файле config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

в файле .env :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://юзер:пассворд@127.0.0.1:3306/имябд
```

Comment: а можно ли как то сделать .env.dev .env.prod? А то получается что один пароль на все окружения

Comment: так и делается. `.env.{environment}`

Comment: А где настраивается {environment}? Я создал .env.local и настройки стали браться от туда, по сути этого достаточно, но не понял где прописано local

Comment: в своем env-файле пишете `APP_ENV=dev` или `APP_ENV=prod`, если вам нужны разные подключения к бд, то создайте два конфига `config/packages/dev/doctrine.yaml` и `config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml`

Comment: Нет,  .env получается как dist, а в env.local нужно писать dev или prod в зависимости от окружения.